# exporting Luke's 'top ranking terms' in an excel file

Tags: lucene, export-to-excel, luke

We can see 'top tanking terms' for a particular field on overview page of Luke. I was wondering if there is any way to export this list of terms in an excel file?

I assumed that this should be a standard requirement and there definitely should be a way in Luke but I didn't find it.

I also did google but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: If memory serves, can't you just right click and copy to clipboard on the top ranking terms?

Comment: It only copies single (selected) term.